# Replace the Method waitForCompltetion() in Job Class by another Method

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, mapreduce, ipc

I am currently using hadoop 2.7.2

I was wondering if there is **another method** from the class `Job` in `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.job` that can replace the method `waitForCompletion()`, because in my project, `waitForCompletion()` calls for another method called `getProxy()` that should be in the `RPC` class in the package `org.apache.hadoop.ipc` in hadoop-common-2.7.2, but it doesn't exist.

However there is a link that proves the existence of the `getProxy()` method in `RPC`: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/ipc/RPC.html

If you want to have a detailed description of the source problem here is the link:

[hadoop mapreduce java program exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37501168/hadoop-mapreduce-java-program-exception-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror?noredirect=1#comment62498030_37501168)

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try adding the below dependency and run once.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>ncku.hpds.tzulitai</groupId>
    <artifactId>distributed-svm</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>cascade-svm-mr</artifactId>
  <name>cascade-svm-mr</name>
  <description>The Cascade SVM approach, implemented with MapReduce</description>
  <build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.7</source>
            <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
   </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>tw.edu.ntu.csie</groupId>
        <artifactId>libsvm</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
            <!-- BIG DATA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Hi Makubex, i added it in the pom file, it gives the same error.

Actually i just figured the cause of the problem:

There is an instance of the `JobClient` classs , from the package `org.apache.hadoop.mapred`, calling for a method `createRPCProxy()`, that doesn't even exist.

Maybe if you have an idea about it, it would very helpful to find an alternative to replace it.

Thank you Makubex.

Comment: I've edited my answer with new dependency. Guess that should solve your issue.

Comment: share your pom.xml

Comment: I cannot share it on commentary because it's tool long.

However here is the link where i got the project, it will be easier for you:   
https://github.com/tzulitai/distributed-svm

In this project, i'm interested in the **cascade svm** project.                                                                                                      I just followed the build info that is located at the bottom of the page of the link that i gave above.                                                                          Thank you for your support  :)

Comment: In the given pom.xml, i'm still seeing hadoop-mapreduce-client-core. Also it's pointing to 2.4.1. The above dependency should be working for 2.7.2.

Comment: Also, if you have a sample data set to test your project, please share so that i can test your project with appropriate dependancy.
+Also provide hadoop jar command for running your jar(incase if you have any user defined parm -D).

Comment: Hi Makubex.

Actually the dataset is from this link (The libsvm website):

https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/datasets/binary.html#a1a

the chosen dataset is "a1a" (the first link): Right click on the link and choose "Save link as...."

**Now according the hadoop jar command:**

Authentication to hadoop user (hduser)
, then, 
`cd distributed-svm`-------------------------`hduser@hadoopmaster:~/distributed-svm$ 'usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop' jar 'location of jar file' ncku.hpds.tzulitai.mapreduce.svm.cascade.CascadeSvm /user/hduser/input/a1a /user/hduser/output`

Regards

Comment: It's asking for args[2] value...
third argument - Subset count
Please let me know what it is...

Comment: I ran with subset value as 14 and it ran without any issue. I dont see any issue with the dependancy i've used. I've updated my answer with the complete pom.xml
FYI, i jus changed jre to 1.7 since i'm using that in my machine.

Comment: 1.7 ,  You mean  the jdk version used in the maven installation ? Because is went in the maven plugin, MANIFEST info , and i saw JDK :  1.7.0

Is that is, or is it something else ??   Regards  :)

Comment: I have 2 questions, just to make sure because i got i little bit confused:

1/  I didn't find Maven-compiler-plugin-2.3.2.jar, and i just downloaded it, where should i put it exactly, in hadoop home directory or in maven home directory?                                                                                                           2/ Also i didn't find Hadood-client-2.7.2.jar and i just downloaded it, should i put in hadoop common directory, or somewhere else ?            Sorry if i took too much of your time to solve the issue

Comment: No probs :)
1)maven compiler plugin 2.3.2 is added in the plugin tag of pom. It comes under .m2 repository
2)Jus give maven install command for cascade-svm-mr
[cascade-svm-mr]$ mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse clean install

Comment: I exported the jar as from eclipse itself.
Also I'm assuming you are running the dependencides. Because if you download the hadoop-client jar directly, you wont be having the other dependancy jars required for it.

Comment: Sorry, for not responding for a long time, but it finally worked. I just checked my hadoop installation, and i got configuration issues (too hard to explain), however, i met another exception. `java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://hadoopmaster:9000/user/hpds/libsvm.jar`. I guess a libsvm jar is missing...

Comment: Cool...:)
Yea i too noticeed libsvm.jar being used in the code. It's already part of the pom.xml. You can move it from your .m2 repo to hdfs.

Comment: I did it, and it worked, however there is another exception, NoSuchElementException

`java.lang.Exception: java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:349)
 at ncku.hpds.tzulitai.mapreduce.svm.cascade.CascadeSvm$SvmTrainer.formSvmProblem(CascadeSvm.java:154)
.........`
This never ends.....

But i got an output, maybe incomplete.

Comment: Just one more thing, what did you get in the output file , or the result was exposed in the terminal ??

Comment: I haven't gone through the code to see what's the expected output.
But I noticed some logger info on the terminal, and some data stored in "_model_file.model" file under the MR output directory.

Comment: The Output i got isn't the expected one, in the middle of the execution: `java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: libsvm/svm_node
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: libsvm/svm_node
 at ncku.hpds.tzulitai.mapreduce.svm.cascade.CascadeSvm$SvmTrainer.formSvmProblem(CascadeSvm.java:156)
at ncku.hpds.tzulitai.mapreduce.svm.cascade.CascadeSvm$SvmTrainer.<init>(CascadeSvm.java:143)` and im sure i put libsvm.jar on hdfs

Comment: Have u added the svm jar in hdfs that is provided as distributed cache in the code.
DistributedCache.addFileToClassPath( new Path("/user/makubex/jar/libsvm-3.17.jar"), cascadeConfs[remainingConfs]);

Comment: Yup, I have specified in the code : `DistributedCache.addFileToClassPath( new Path("/user/hpds/libsvm-3.17.jar"), cascadeConfs[remainingConfs])`, then, inside the user directory, i created a directory hpds in hdfs, and i put libsvm-3.17.jar, but still nothing :(

Comment: svm_node class is available in the libsvm-3.17.jar.
Your distributed cache is not working properly.

Comment: Finally, it worked.  
Actually the problem was not from the distributed cache, but from the jdk version of the libsvm.jar file that i downloaded,  i was supposed to take a libsvm.jar built on 1.8 jdk, but i used 1.7 jdk, because i'm currently using 1.8.  
Thanks a lot makubex :)